# Problem with risk table not showing up when combining multiple tidycmprsk::cuminc plots with cowplot or ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, cowplot

I'm having problems when trying to combine multiple cuminc plots (with tidycmprsk), the risk table doesn't show up in the final combined plot, either using cowplot, or ggarrange.

```
df <- tibble::tibble(id = c(1:10), 
                     time = c(3, 15, 8, 9, 7, 12, 18, 20, 6, 14), 
                     status = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)) %>% 
          mutate(status = as.factor(status))

p <- cuminc(Surv(time, status)~1, data = df) %>% 
  ggcuminc() +
  add_risktable()
```

[image: inital plot with the risk table below]

I tried to combine 2 plots side by side, but the risk tables disappear

```
ggarrange(p, p, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image: combined plot without the risk tables]

Comment: `ggpubr::ggarrange` is just a wrapper for `cowplot::plot_grid` so it's to be expected that these produce the same result. The issue seems to be that `ggsurvfit::add_risktable` adds an additional layer to the plot, whereas `plot_grid` also use layers to store the different plots, most likely copying only the first of each individual plot.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to switch to `patchwork` which however still requires to build the `ggcuminc` plot using `ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit_build()`:

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(survival)
library(tidycmprsk)
library(patchwork)

p <- cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = df) |> 
  ggcuminc() +
  add_risktable()
#> Plotting outcome "1".

list(
  ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit_build(p),
  ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit_build(p)
) |> 
  wrap_plots()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, though if you build the plots first so will the original `ggarrange`/`plot_grid` approach so that seems to be the key part.